# How to return an NSMutableArray from an NSSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsset

I'm able to put the contents of an `NSSet` into an `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [set allObjects];
```

The compiler complains though because [set allObjects] returns an `NSArray` not an `NSMutableArray`. How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Since `-allObjects` returns an array, you can create a mutable version with:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[set allObjects]];
```

Or, alternatively, if you want to handle the object ownership:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[set allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Note: there is a subtle difference in the two methods if `set` is `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved crashing by using **NSMutableArray's** method 'addObjectsFromArray' to assign all **NSSet** objects to **NSMutableArray** like:

```
[mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:[cg_Schedule.schedule_Days allObjects]];
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score -3):

For an ordered set use:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[myOrderedSet array] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an NSSet `- array` method.